# SQL sort by column if column has a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

I have two tables, joined together.

1st table

```
activity: id, name, date_created
```

2nd table

```
activity_meta: id, activity_id, meta_key, meta_value
```

I would like to sort results this way:

FIRST: Entries with activity_meta.meta_key = sticky and activity_meta.meta_value=1, ordered by activity.date_created DESC

NEXT: All other entries that have/or don't have activity_meta.meta_key = sticky but activity_meta.meta_value other than 1, order by activity.date_created DESC

Here's a start:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
FROM activity AS a INNER JOIN
     activity_meta AS ameta
     ON a.id = ameta.activity_id
 WHERE ameta.meta_key = 'sticky'
 ORDER BY ameta.meta_key DESC, a.date_created DESC
```

Something like the above, but I don't know how to set up those cases.

Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desire results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the `id`s, then I would expect to see a `group by`.  Then, conditional aggregation gives you what you need for the ordering:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM activity a INNER JOIN
     activity_meta ameta
     ON a.id = ameta.activity_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY MAX(ameta.meta_key = 'sticky' and ameta.meta_value = '1') DESC, 
         a.date_created DESC;
```

This uses the MySQL feature that boolean expressions are treated as integers.  So, a true value is treated as "1" and a false value as "0".

Comment: Today, sir, you were a god. Thanks!